# DeepAI Image Generation API is returning error code 400

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I recently subscribed DeepAI Image Generation API to build my mobile app. The API is returning error code 400. I am using Volley library in Android Studio project. Kindly let me know where I am doing it wrong. Thank you.

logs:

> E/DeepAI: API request failed with HTTP status code: 400
> E/DeepAI: Response body: {"err": "error processing given inputs from request"}

```
public class DeepAIImageGenerator {

private static final String API_URL = "https://api.deepai.org/api/text2img";
private static final String API_KEY = "abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc";

private Context context;
private ImageView imageView;

public DeepAIImageGenerator(Context context, ImageView imageView) {
    this.context = context;
    this.imageView = imageView;
}

public void generateImage(String text) {
    try {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        // Prepare the request body
        JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
        requestBody.put("text", text);

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, API_URL, requestBody,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            String imageUrl = response.getString("output_url");
                            loadImage(imageUrl);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (error.networkResponse != null) {
                            Log.e("DeepAI", "API request failed with HTTP status code: " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                            String responseBody = new String(error.networkResponse.data);
                            Log.e("DeepAI", "Response body: " + responseBody);
                        } else {
                            Log.e("DeepAI", "API request failed: " + error.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Api-Key", API_KEY);
                return headers;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(request);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void loadImage(String imageUrl) {
    ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(imageUrl,
            new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
                }
            },
            0,
            0,
            ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE,
            null,
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("DeepAI", "Image request failed: " + error.toString());
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(imageRequest);
}
```

}